# Adding remove button with in function using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to add remove button but unfortunately the populated removed button from the addRow function not working. I have no idea what I am missing .

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.deleteRowButton').click(DeleteRow);
    });
    function DeleteRow(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    }
    $(function () {
        //$("#addRow").click(function ()
        $(document).on("click", "#addRow", function(){
            $('#container tr:last').after('<tr>\n\
            <td><select name="materialID[]" ><option value="0">Select A Material</option><?php echo str_replace("'", "\\'", $options); ?></select></td>\n\
            <td>Quantity: <input type="text" name="qty[]" /></td>\n\
            <td><select name="SupplierID[]" ><option value="0">Select A Supplier</option><?php echo str_replace("'", "\\'", $options2); ?></select></td>\n\
            <td><button class="deleteRowButton" type="button">Remove</button></td>\n\n\
        </tr>');
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are adding your html dinamically, the event won't be in the added button, because the events were attached in the buttons that were on the page when the document was ready, and it won't be attached on new buttons.

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.deleteRowButton', function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    }
}
```

Give it a try and let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The initial assignment of the DeleteRow function with jQuery is ran against everything on the page at the time.  When you add a new row, the assignment hasn't been added to that particular (new) element as it never existed before.

In order to get it to work, you'll either need to add an on-click event, or re-run the jQuery to add the event to the .deleteRowButton classes so all the new ones have it.

Comment: <td>
                <button class="deleteRowButton" type="button">Remove</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <br/>
    </table>
    <button id="addRow" type="button">More item</button>
    <input type="submit" id="gobutton" name="additem"  value="Order" />

Comment: sorry couldn`t add the full code, do you mean this code

Comment: Where you run " $('.deleteRowButton').click(DeleteRow);", this is only done with whatever is on the page at the time.  Any new elements will need the event handler adding to them, either by an explicit "onclick" added to the button, or that bit of jQuery running again to ensure all of the deleteRowButton classes have the event on them